# SQL to QueryDSL ... why this way to construct the query?

Tags: sql, querydsl

I have the following query,

```
SELECT n.id, network_name, count(DISTINCT a.id), count(DISTINCT w.id), count(DISTINCT v.id) 
FROM network n
  LEFT JOIN account a ON a.network_id = n.id
  LEFT JOIN meat w ON w.account_id = a.id
  LEFT JOIN fish v ON v.account_id = a.id
GROUP BY n.id, network_name
```

Why to construct the same SQL query using QueryDSL I need to "invert" some logic ? Shouldn't be easier if the order and name of the method could match the SQL ?

This is the query I needed to create in order to get the same result. I was quite a bit of time to understand this logic.

```
new JPAQuery(entityManager).from(meat, fish)
        .rightJoin(meat.account, account)
        .rightJoin(fish.account, account)
        .rightJoin(account.network, network)
        .groupBy(network)
        .where(network.id.eq(id))
        .singleResult(network, account.id.countDistinct(), fish.id.countDistinct(), meat.id.countDistinct());
```

Some points:

- Instead of select from the top table **Network**, I need to select from the bottom, in this case **Meat** and **Fish**.
- Invert the leftJoin to rightJoin and also the order. On the SQL I start by leftJoin the account/network, and on QueryDSL I need to start to join the meat/fish and accounts. This should be related to the previous point.

Comment: "I need to "invert" some logic " ... No you do not ! What was the problem, I did not get it...

Comment: @Meiko, look at the SQL query. I would be more simple to just write the same query in the QueryDSL, using leftJoin instead or rightJoin, and keep the same order.

Comment: Ah now I see, you do not create sql with `JPAQuery`. You should compare the JPQL that is created from querydsl with the JPQL you would write...

Comment: Please explain what you want to do, what you tried and what the problem is. Additional you should add a hint, that you are using JPA (`JPAQuery`) For me, your question is not very understandable.

Comment: I don't want to do nothing, I just want to find out why we need to write the QueryDSL this way, that seems not logic to me. If I construct a query with LEFT JOIN, I was thinking to do the same with QueryDSL I should also use leftJoin. The question is: why querydsl is implemented this way and not the normal way that we are used to write SQL ?

Comment: Again, JPAQuery creates JPQL no SQL.

Comment: Your question could be: Why is the structure of the JPQL query (here generated with QueryDSL),to let my program work,  different form a SQL statement, I can write in my db console.